# Chromatic number with $\delta(G)>(\frac{k-2}{k-1})n$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Let $k\geq 2$ be an integer. Prove that if $G$ is a $k$-colorable graph of order $n$ such that $\delta(G)>(\frac{k-2}{k-1})n$, then $G$ is $k$-chromatic.

I supposed to the contrary that $\chi(G)=k-1$. I was trying to find a contradiction to the hypothesis. Can you help me to find it?

Comment: Are you related with [zwim](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/399263/zwim)?

Comment: You are right. I edited my question. I mean I wrote original question. Can you take a look at it?

Comment: I thought that if I proved $\delta(G)\leq |C_i|(k-1)$ ($C_i$ is a color class) then a proof would be done. But, it is not working as your counter example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us transform the statement, step by step, into a more perspicuous form. The following statements are equivalent:

(1) For $k\ge2$ and $G$ of order $n,$ if $\chi(G)\le k$ and $\delta(G)\gt\left(\frac{k-2}{k-1}\right)n,$ then $\chi(G)=k.$

(2) For $k\ge2$ and $G$ of order $n,$ if $\delta(G)\gt\left(\frac{k-2}{k-1}\right)n,$ then $\chi(G)\ge k.$

Let $k=h+1.$

(3) For $h\ge1$ and $G$ of order $n,$ if $\delta(G)\gt\left(\frac{h-1}h\right)n,$ then $\chi(G)\gt h.$

(4) For $h\ge1$ and $G$ of order $n,$ if $\chi(G)\le h,$ then $\delta(G)\le\left(\frac{h-1}h\right)n.$

The proof of (4) is straightforward. Let $C_1,C_2,\dots,C_h$ be color classes for a proper $h$-coloring of $G,$ with $|C_1|\ge|C_2|\ge\cdots\ge|C_h|.$ If $v\in C_1,$ then
$$\delta(G)\le\deg v\le|C_2|+\cdots+|C_h|\le\left(\frac{h-1}h\right)n.$$

Comment: Can you let me know why the last equality $|C_2|+\cdots+|C_h| \leq (\frac{h-1}{h})n$ holds?

Comment: @kswim Since $C_1$ is the biggest color class, $$n=|C_1|+|C_2|+\cdots+|C_h|\le h|C_1|$$ $$|C_1|\ge\frac nh$$ $$|C_2|+\cdots+|C_h|=n-|C_1|\le n-\frac nh=\left(\frac{h-1}h\right)n$$

Comment: @kswim In other words, if you divide $n$ beans into $h$ piles, then the biggest pile will have at least $\frac nh$ beans, and the rest will have at most $(1-\frac1h)n$ beans.

Comment: Thank you for your help!